# Pre-standardisation behaviour of `__proto__`

Tags: javascript, prototype

The ECMA-262 standard, since its 6th edition specifies `__proto__` as a property descriptor defined on `Object.prototype` ([ECMA-262 6th Ed. § B.2.2.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__)). It also specifies special behaviour for `__proto__` as a key in object literals ([ECMA-262 6th Ed. § B.3.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-__proto__-property-names-in-object-initializers)) that ordinary, user-defined property descriptors on `Object.prototype` cannot replicate.

Before it appeared in the formal ECMAScript standard, I remember the feature being a de-facto standard originating in Mozilla's JavaScript engine, later implemented by Chromium as well.

In those pre-ECMA implementations, was it ever the case that `__proto__` was not implemented via `Object.prototype` at all? Specifically, I am wondering if an implementation existed where this code:

```
var x = Object.create(null);
x.__proto__ = { a: true };
console.info(x.a);
```

would print `true` to the console (assuming `Object.create` or equivalent was available).

Comment: https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2012-May/023022.html refers to '[t]he de-facto and soon to be de-jure `Object.prototype.__proto__` standard', so presumably it always was a property of `Object.prototype`. But I'd like some confirmation.

Comment: <https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=837630>, in turn linking to <https://twitter.com/olov/status/298395329945030657>